# How to select only first 5 results and then show more.. option?

Tags: php, mysql, search

How can i select the first 5 results and then add a see more option?

Below is the current code:

```
  <?php

   $query="SELECT * FROM messages where u_id = '$uid' ORDER BY id DESC";
   $result=mysql_query($query);

   $num=mysql_numrows($result);

    mysql_close();

    echo "";

     $i=0;
     while ($i < $num) {

  $otheris=mysql_result($result,$i,"sender_full_name"); 
  $sysid=mysql_result($result,$i,"sender_id");
   $dob=mysql_result($result,$i,"dob");

    // If $dob is empty
   if (empty($dob)) {

   $dob = "No new messages - 
   <a  id=missingdob href=/test.php?id=$uid>
   <bold>check later</bold></a>";
   }

   echo "<br><div id=linkcontain>
   <a id=otherlink href=$mem/profile.php?id=$uid>
    $manitis</a>
         <br><div id=dobpres>$dob</div></div>";

   echo "";

    $i++;
      }

       ?>
```

Comment: I assume you know about `LIMIT`... right?? Or... is that what you wanted to know?

Answer (score 2):

You should try to select 6 rows first time and if you get 6 records then show first 5 with a "show more option"

```
"SELECT * FROM messages where u_id = '$uid' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 6";
```

For subsequent times you should have your query like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM messages where u_id = '$uid' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 6, 5";
"SELECT * FROM messages where u_id = '$uid' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 11, 5";
"SELECT * FROM messages where u_id = '$uid' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 16, 5";
...
...
```

And every time "show more option" if you are able to fetch requested number of records.

Comment: you missing first record - LIMIT starts at 0

Comment: ANd how can i detect more than 5 records and show the option for see more...  thanks Anubhava.

Comment: Well if you notice in every SQL we are fetching 1 extra record than what we have to display (eg: in 2nd select we fetch upto 11th record but you will display only upto 10th record). If your latest select did get 5 records back from DB always display "show more" link in the browser, once user clicks on that link fetch next 5 records. When you reach to the last less than 5 records in the table your fetch count of <5 will tell you NOT to display "show more" link in the browser.

Comment: @AAA: If you want to see the working php code of this pagination mechanism, please see my answer on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5354244/how-to-get-query-to-transfer-to-subsquent-pages-when-paginating-results/5355969#5355969

Answer (score 1):

```
$query="SELECT * FROM messages where u_id = '$uid' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5";
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html

you could consider LIMIT 6 display only up to 5 if 6th exist display there is more options...

Comment: One follow up.  How do i show "see more" only where there are more than 5 results??

Comment: you could consider LIMIT 6 display only up to 5 if 6th exist display there is more options...

Answer (score 1):

```
window.onload = function(){

$(".box").hide();
$(".box").slice(0, 5).show(); // select the first ten
$("#load").click(function(e){ // click event for load more
    e.preventDefault();
    $("div:hidden").slice(0, -1).show(); // select next hidden divs and show them
    $("#load-more-div").html(' ');
});}
```

Comment: could you elaborate to help us understand this code?

Comment: @SimasJoneliunas yes. lets say you have 100's of div with class "box" and you want to show only 5 at first and then after click on "load more button" (which will have id =load) you want to show rest of divisions.

Code :

<div class="box"></div>     <!-- similiar 100's of div -->
<button id="load">Load More</button>