# How to get query to transfer to subsquent pages when paginating results

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I've been going through all the pagination questions and answers on the site, and among all the long-drawn out code and OO solutions, this code is among the shortest and simplest:

```
<?php  
// insert your mysql connection code here  
$perPage = 10; 
$page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1; 
$startAt = $perPage * ($page - 1);  
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM table"; 
$r = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($query));  
$totalPages = ceil($r['total'] / $perPage);  
$links = ""; 
for ($i = 1; $i <= $totalPages; $i++) { $links .= ($i != $page )  ? "<a href='index.php?page=$i'>Page $i</a> " : "$page "; }   
$query = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY title LIMIT $startAt, $perPage";  
$r = mysql_query($query);  
// display results here the way you want  
echo $links; // show links to other pages
```

But I still can't see how to regenerate the query with the updated `LIMIT` on the subsequent pages. None of the messages make this clear, and I continue to get blank second pages no matter which code I try. I'd really appreciate it if someone could explain how to get the query results to the next pages.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use the OFFSET token in your query. Like so:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY title LIMIT $perPage OFFSET $perPage * $page";
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: The range is being provided to the query, it has the record number to start at and the number of records to display. The problem is how to get all the query information and the table structure for displaying the results to follow through to subsequent pages.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is in the code you posted? I tried this and it works fine for me.

Comment: My searchterm for the query is pulled originally with POST. I assume that since GET is being used to get the page number when the link is followed that the query isn't being rerun because it doesn't have the searchterm it needs, does that sound right? Is it just a matter of adding the searchterm to the href for the linked pages? If so, what should I add? Tried adding &?search=$searchterm to <a href='index.php?page=$i'> but this obviously isn't right.

Comment: Sorry, meant <a href='index.php?page=$i&search=$searchterm'> but when I make this change and try to use $_GET['search'] to save the value for use in the search on subsequent pages, then the code falls down.

Comment: @Chelle: To avoid the problem of how the data is passed I always use `$_REQUEST` instead of `$_GET` or `$_POST`. If you run the query for every page you show you have to send the searchterm in some way. If you are using a string containing spaces for the searchterm you have to encode it. That may be the problem. Yo should try the link like this: `<a href='index.php?page=<?php echo $i; ?>&search=<?php echo url_encode($searchterm); ?>'>`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need to do select count(*) every time. I would suggest doing it like this:

```
<?php
/* establish the connection */
$mysqli = new mysqli (
            'localhost',  // The host to connect to
            'username',       // The user to connect as
            'password',   // The password to use
            'dbname');     // The default database to query

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s<br />\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$perPage = 10;
$page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
$startAt = $perPage * ($page - 1);

/* Send a query to the server */
if ($result = $mysqli->query(
     "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY title limit $startAt, $perPage")) {
    $rowCnt = $result->num_rows;
    echo "<h3>Page: $page</h3>\n";

    /* Fetch the results of the query and show results*/
    while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
        printf("%s - %s<br/>\n", $row['orderDate'], $row['orderDescription']);
    }

    /* Show next page, previous page links dynamically */
    echo "<p>\n";
    // generate previous page link if current page no is after 1st page
    if ($page > 1)
        printf("<a href='%s?page=%d'>Previous Page</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;\n", 
           $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"], ($page-1));

    // generate next page link if we were able to fetch $perPage rows    
    if ($rowCnt == $perPage) 
        printf("<a href='%s?page=%d'>Next Page</a>\n", 
           $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"], ($page+1));
    echo "</p>\n";

    /* Destroy the result set and free the memory used for it */
    $result->close();
}

/* close the connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

I am using new mysqli extension of php, here is the [php mysqli reference documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)